# Search Text Files with PHP from User Input

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, search

Looking for a solution to search through a list of Zip Codes. I have a text file with a bunch of zip codes that we service. Would like to have a form on the website asking for the user to input their zip code to see if we service that area. If it does, display a message saying that we do, if not, saying that we don't. Thought PHP would be the best solution for my problem, but I'm a total noob when it comes to that.

I have my form set up, I'm just not sure how to search the text file and display the answer in another div?

```
<form action="zipcode.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

UPDATE: Preferably an AJAX solution!

Comment: Do you want AJAX or just a regular POST?

Comment: AJAX would be the best solution!

Comment: @SethDouwsma Consider trying out my answer below, tested and working with your zipcodes file.

Comment: You're the best! Worked like a charm. Is there a way to do that using AJAX without the page reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## AJAX method (tested)

---

### PHP handler

(find_in_file_ajax.php)

```
<?php
$search = $_POST['search'];
$text = file_get_contents('zipcodes.txt');
$lines = explode("\n", $text);
if(in_array($_POST['search'], $lines)){ //checks if ZIP is in array
    echo "ZIP code found";
}else{
    echo "ZIP code does not exist";
}
?>
```

### HTML form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
.update {

font-family:Georgia;
color:#0000FF;

}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    $(".search_button").click(function() {
        // getting the value that user typed
        var searchString = $("#search_box").val();
        // forming the queryString
        var data = 'search='+ searchString;

        // if searchString is not empty
        if(searchString) {
            // ajax call
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "find_in_file_ajax.php",
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function(html) { // this happens before actual call
                    $("#results").html(''); 
                    $("#searchresults").show();
                    $(".word").html(searchString);
               },
               success: function(html){ // this happens after we get results
                    $("#results").show();
                    $("#results").append(html);
              }
            });    
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search_box" class='search_box'/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="search_button" /><br />
</form>
</div>      
<div>

<div id="searchresults">Search results: <span id="results" class="update"></span>
</div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

## Original answer

### Tested

First the file needs to be accessed via `file_get_contents`, then explode each entry and extract the zip code search in question.

Assuming the zipcodes.txt file is in the following format:

43505
43517
43518
43526
43543

**NOTE**: If 43505 is queried, it will be found. Unlike 4350 or 3505 will not be found, so it's a unique query.

Consider the following:

```
<?php
$search = $_POST['search'];
$text = file_get_contents('zipcodes.txt');
$lines = explode("\n", $text);
if(in_array($_POST['search'], $lines)){ //checks if ZIP is in array
    echo "ZIP code found.";
}else{
    echo "ZIP code does not exist";
}
?>
```

Comment: You're the best! Worked like a charm. Is there a way to do that using AJAX without the page reload?

Comment: @SethDouwsma I'm glad I could help. As for the Ajax method, you can easily implement it, but I don't have enough experience with Ajax, yet I would think that all you would need to do is to find an Ajax example where the POST file to be called, would be the code above, in theory, but am confident it will work.

Comment: @SethDouwsma And if you feel I have answered your question, to accept my answer with the checkmark over to the left under the arrows, so that it will not remain in the unanswered category, cheers.

Comment: This makes so much more sense now that I've seen it work live. Thank you so much Fred!

Comment: @SethDouwsma You're right, Ajax is great. I've dabbled in it enough to have found you a solution, and you're very much welcome Seth, glad I could help, cheers! (*Peace*)

Answer (score 1):

Saw your edit...the below is PHP.

I would do something like

```
$lines = file("/path/to/file.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); //reads all values into array
if(in_array($_POST['search'], $lines)){ //checks if ZIP is in array
    echo "found zip code";
}else{
    echo "zip code does not exist";
}
```

As long as there isn't a VERY LARGE amount of zip codes...this should be fine. Also, what is the format of your file? This may not work.

Comment: I have around 350 zip codes to search through and might be more in the future. I don't see where the user's item is being used to search through text file?

Comment: @SethDouwsma Give us an example of how your text file is stored.

Comment: Yes, please provide an example of your ZIP code file. Also, the users data will be accessible from zipcode.php with `$_POST['search']`. Use the that in place of `"ZIP_CODE"` above.

Comment: That format will work with the code above. 350 zips is not very many, so this should be perfectly fine. From zipcode.php (the place you are submitting the form to) use the above code.

Comment: Ahhhh! I see, okay, what about an AJAX solution so I don't have to reload the page? Any thoughts on that! You guys have been a big help!

Comment: I found this tutorial, seems to be what I'm looking for. I'll give this a try. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Comment: @AlexO'rourke Have you tested your code? When I run it with the OP's .txt file, and enter a number inside it, doesn't come up with a successfull result.

Comment: @Fred, I forgot to tell it to ignore new lines :) sorry! Edited above. But OP says he is trying some Jquery tutorial.

Comment: @AlexO'rourke Saw that, well done. Gave you an UPvote, cheers ;-) (*Peace*)