# Html+java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this code of a search bar engine.

```
<form id="frmSearch"  class="search1" method="get" action="default.html" /> <input class="search" id="txtSearch" type="text" name="search_bar" size="31" maxlength="255"        value="" 
 <style="left: 396px; top: 20000px; width: 293px; height: 60px;" />  

<input class="search2" type="submit" name="submition" value="Search" style=" padding-   bottom:20px; left: 300px; top: 0px; height: 50px" />
 <input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="default.html" />  

<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() {
         window.location = 'http://www.google.ro/search?q=' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
         return false;
     }         
</script>
```

1. I want to make the search button,when user clicks it. It should search through local text file.
2. After it started the search for the key word to make refresh steady for the same word for which started to search.
3. To bring me all the keyword found on the txt to my graphical interface as small frames....

thank's for your help

Comment: Your problem is bit unclear. Can you please make some changes so can get your exact issue ?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a coding service. Do you actually have a problem? It sounds like your asking for a full code solution to meet your requirements. What have you tried already and what issues are you running into.

Comment: @Horia If you are trying to replicate something like google search you are looking at classic Ajax. What you need is Ajax call to server on button click which will access text file and search for keyword (backend logic of search through text file). You could return back results as Array of Strings in JSON format. On browser you can append all results under search textbox in list items based on number of matches list will grow in size. Ajax will answer page refresh issue and dynamic list items will address 3rd issue. If you need it in frame you can append html dom of your liking with css.

Comment: I don t know how to make the search engine read and bring my info back from al local text file in my graphical interface. Sorry to have bothered you with my question ste2425 but i'm at  the beginning.

Comment: @pratikwebdev Thanks for your answer.But i dont want to relplicate google search.I whrote that for better unterstanding. I want  my search engine bring me back the information found in the text file after the keyword are found.

Comment: Have a look at this, will get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493282/search-text-files-with-php-from-user-input

Comment: @horia please don't miss understand my comment. You are not bothering me or anyone else with your question. However your question isn't clear on exactly what your asking. It looks more like a pitch. You need to state what you have already tried and the technical issues your facing from it, or the architectural issues or lack of knowledge if your struggling to work out how to accomplish the task.

Comment: enter word for search in the search area-press the button- and the search engine look for it in a local text file, to make  refresh (every 10 seconds) in case the  file are update and bring be back the info found to my interface after he search the text file.

Comment: *and show the results on my local host page.

Answer (score 0):

First, I advice you to read [the Quick Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) in StackOverflow, to know how to use this Website.

Also, I think you correct your HTML :

```
<form id="frmSearch"  class="search1" method="get" action="default.html">
    <input class="search" id="txtSearch" type="text" name="search_bar" size="31" maxlength="255" />
    <input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="default.html/>
    <input class="search2" type="submit" name="submition" placeholder="Search" style="padding-bottom:20px; left: 300px; top: 0px; height: 50px" />
</form>
```

`<form>` tag is not an autoclosing tag : you can read [this official documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html) for this tag.

For all the HTML Specification you can read [this](https://www.w3.org/html/).

and your JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() {
        window.location = 'http://www.google.ro/search?q=' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
    }
</script>
```

Now, your HTML **SYNTAX** is correct, but is not according with what you want...

We want to see in your Javascript, you can't verify if the value of your element 'txtSearch' is empty...

If you want to create a search bar, and load a part of your page in relation with the search box (your input type text), I advice you to learn what is [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).

You do not need to use a `<form>` tag if you don't want to reload all your page for display the results (images or other...) in your page...

Also, I noticed that you add the 'JQuery' tag on this conversation... but, in your sample **you don't use JQuery**... you just use JavaScript!

If you want to use JQuery, this can help you to create your Ajax Request (you can read [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for that).

Comment: I dont know how to do it...i've tried..:(( if someone have time to put the code on a paper to see how its done.

Comment: @Horia Do you have a server logic which searches and returns results? That is for url `http://www.google.ro/search?q=`

Comment: I know It's not easy, but with all link in my post you can do it! Web programmation is not easy... Do not be lazy and search by itself! Otherwise, you will never understand the processes! 

If you want a finished code, ready to be used in your case, you are mistaken website, look for a freelance, and pay its code :P

Comment: Nope, i dont want to use it online....the url is for example...i need only the button works - when you press it to start search for a key word in a txt file which i have on my computer and take the info from there and bring me the results in to my page.

Comment: @Horia If (since your test) have a problem, Explain it in your post (with code of your test...) , I help you if  I can.

Comment: @Horia Most important thing you need is server/serach logic on backend. If you have it front end code it wont be too much of a big deal. As Doc mentioned in his answer all the links will help setting up simple ajax call for button click event. All the work is to be done by server logic. Update your post with relative info and take it from there on.